# Find matching locations / distances without using scripting in Elasticsearch?

Tags: performance, groovy, elasticsearch, geospatial

I'm using Elasticsearch to store user locations and their distance preference when finding other users. This is stored in a `location` geo_point and a `distance` integer.

For example, the index contains these documents:

- Alice, located at [0,100] and looking for users within 100 meters;
- Bob, located at [100,0] and looking for users within 50 meters.

When Carlos, located at [0,0], searches within 100 meters I need my query to return Alice, but *not* Bob (since Bob only wants users within 50m, and Carlos is 100m away).

**In other words, I want to return all documents `D` such that `D.reach` contains `Carlos.location` and `Carlos.reach` contains `D.location`.**

As far as I can see, the only way to do this is by comparing the distances with scripting like so:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "script": {
            "script": "min(doc['distance'].value, distance) >= doc['location'].arcDistance(lat, lon)",
            "params": {
                "distance": 100,
                "lat": 0,
                "lon": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd [rather avoid scripting](http://code972.com/blog/2015/03/84-elasticsearch-one-tip-a-day-avoid-costly-scripts-at-all-costs) if at all possible. Is there an alternative method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val)'s answer pointing me in the right direction, I used the following solution.

Documents look like this, containing users' location as `geo_point` and reach as a `geo_shape`.

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "location" : [1,0],
    "reach" : {
        "type": "shape",
        "coordinates": [1,0],
        "radius": 100
    }
}
```

The query then contains two filters; one for matching Carlos' location inside the users' reach, and another for matching the user's location inside the Carlos' reach.

```
{
    "filter": {
        "and" : [
            {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "preferences.reach": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": Carlos.location
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": Carlos.distance,
                    "user.location" : Carlos.location
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This could be done with two `geo_shape`s but `geo_point`s are more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Another way worth investigating would be using a [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html) [`circle`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html#_circle). So instead of (or in addition to) storing discrete values for `location` and `distance`, you could store a combination of those two values as a circle representing the `reach` of the user. In your mapping, it would look like this:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "reach": {
            "type": "geo_shape",
            "tree": "quadtree",
            "precision": "10cm"
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you index your document, you'd specify the `reach` circle like this:

```
{
    "name": "Alice",
    "reach" : {
        "type" : "circle",
        "coordinates" : [0.0, 100.0],    <---- Alice's current location field
        "radius" : "100m"                <---- Alice's current distance field
    }
}
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "reach" : {
        "type" : "circle",
        "coordinates" : [100.0, 0.0],    <---- Bob's current location field
        "radius" : "50m"                 <---- Bob's current distance field
    }
}
```

At this point, all your users will have a `geo_shape` associated to them representing their reach. Now you can unleash the power of ES geo queries and filters in order to find intersections or what have you, for instance by using the [`geo_shape` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-filter.html). The idea is to filter on another `geo_shape` representing the reach of the user who is searching other users (e.g. Carlos above)

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "circle",
                            "coordinates" : [0.0, 0.0]   <--- Carlos location
                            "radius": "100m"             <--- Carlos reach
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query will find all documents (i.e. users) whose reach intersects the Carlos' reach specified in the filter. Give it a shot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but this isn't quite what I need. This will calculate the intersection of A.reach and C.reach, whereas I want to ensure A.location exists inside C.reach AND C.location exists inside A.reach. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Presumably I could use an AND to perform two filters; one providing a Point shape to match the document's reach, and another providing a Circle shape to match the document's location?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that, too, if that was your intent. Checking if a point lies within a circle is easy with the geo_shape filter.